What is recommended when publishing multiple variations of a message?
I'm looking for a recommended approach for the following scenario.
I have an API endpoint through which one can add/remove their friends.
PATCH /api/me/friends HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "friends": ["GUID"]
}

After updating the DB, the system publishes the event FriendsUpdated, which contains the resulting collection of friends after applying the change.
This is, if the current value is ["John", "Jane"] and then I add "James" and remove "Jane", the system will publish the following message:
{
  "Person": "...",
  "Friends": ["John", "James"]
}

The thing is that there is also the need of having another event that tells the actual changes that were performed, this is, which friends were added and which ones were removed. Something like this:
{
  "Person": "...",
  "Friends": {
    "Added": ["James"],
    "Removed": ["Jane"]
  }
}


What is the recommended approach to follow to accomplish the scenario described above?
All I can think of is to have the following logic:

Determine the changes being applied.
Update the DB.
Get current collection of friends.
Publish FriendsUpdated, which contains the actual friends.
Publish FriendsChanged (or something similar) containing the specific changes.

This could be an acceptable solution, but I'm willing to know if there are better ways of doing this. Thanks!

Are the FriendsUpdated and FriendsChanged events are processed by the same consumer or different consumers?

Do you have control over the events' shape?

"The thing is that there is also the need of having another event that tells the actual changes that were performed" - can you please give the actual reason for that? Possibly it will allow us to understand your case better.

@PeterCsala, The events are processed by different consumers, and yes, I can change their schema.

@GuruStron, The FriendsUpdated event is consumed by components that keep a copy of a person's friends (these components do not need to know what has changed, they only need the current state of the data).
The FriendsChanged event would be a new event meant to be consumed by components that require to know what has changed.

Are you looking for a trade-off analysis single event vs dedicated events? Or what exactly is your question?

@PeterCsala, Yes, pretty much. My main concern is if, from a good practices or design perspective, it is OK (or common) to publish different variations of a message (or even different messages) from a single business operation.

I tried to perform my trade-off analysis from the following perspectives:

event payload
producer side (emission logic, schema management)
consumer side (processing logic, performance, flexibility)

I've also tried to name situations when you should either pick them or avoid them.
Single event
In this case the reported/emitted event contains all the information for all interested parties.
From the producer-side that means the event emission logic is simple but the event's payload is bloated.
From the consumer-side that means the transferred data might be larger than the useful/profitable data.
Containing all the things that might be useful for anyone is generally considered as a good practice if you as a producer don't know upfront who and when will process your data.
In a high volume and/or high velocity system this approach can have worse performance than multiple events.
Multiple events
In this case the reported/emitted events are focused and concise.
From the producer-side that means the events emission logic could be more complex (like all successfully published or none), it also requires the management of multiple event schemas.
From the consumer-side that means the event processing can be quicker and more straightforward. Also there is a possibility to subscribe to  more events, process them independently (at different rate, on different resources).
If the events are used for example for service-to-service communication then having multiple lighter, dedicated events are better.
This approach can be problematic if you need to correlate the events.

This is very helpful. I'll opt for having multiple events as that suits better for my case.
